# Pandas rolling sum over one calendar year window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have a daily data index pd.DataFrame over which I'd like to compute rolling sums using one calendar year but this leads to the error `ValueError: window must be an integer`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01').date()
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31').date()

dfo = pd.DataFrame(data=0,
                   index=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=BDay()),
                   columns=['col1', 'col2'])
dfo.index = dfo.index.date

# ... fill in some data and then:

dfo = dfo.rolling('1Y').sum()
```

leads to the error: `ValueError: window must be an integer`

Since I have daily BD data I could just use a window of size 252 i.e. average business trading days per year but for my use-case it would be ideal to use a calendar year instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is an `object` `dtype`. A rolling window using a time interval expects the dataframe to have a `datetimeindex`. You can simply convert the index by doing:

```
dfo.index = pd.to_datetime(dfo.index)
```

And taking the rolling sum for a year using:

```
dfo.rolling('365D').sum()
```

See also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects to see which frequency strings can be used to specify a rolling time window.